# Change "Selenium test files" folder in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, selenium, osx-snow-leopard

How to change "Selenium test files" folder in NetBeans 6.9.1 (+ MacOs 10.6.6 if it's specific)
I can't find any setting for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place I've found to change the path is under "{project directory}\nbproject\project.properties" file
change
selenium.src.dir=

when you restart netbeans you should be able to pick a new directory.